# How to Populate UITableViewCells with data from URL?

Tags: web-services, ios7, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am quite new to iOS. I Just want to know few methods to populate the table view with data from specific URLString.

Comment: http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-16-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some link's for you to check out [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) , [link2](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/) and [link3](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/). Also simple scenario is that we hit url and get some response from it(json form) then we parse it and store it in NSMutableArray or whatever that suit's up. Then that array we use in cellforrowatindex method like cell.textlabel.text = [array objectatindex:indexpath.row]. This is just a simple overview kinda stuff. Hope useful for you!

Comment: ,Thanks i got it..... One more help please.. I want to Update Data from my Operator app to User app.Should i use POST method or what? If POST method,then HOW?

Comment: I didn't get. Whats operator app ? but still post method is good to use and deciding which to use depends upon ur need's. So, go ahead and dig up what are your need. Also go for google that would provide you with lot's of post method example's.

Comment: @ walle84 what i am saying is that operator will update the price and at user end price will updated...

Comment: For client-side you could use background fetch so as to keep check with operator whether price is updated or not. If yes, then update it on client side too with your logic.